# Открытие страницы с проверкой

Tags: java, android, webview

Создал WebView:

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Но при проверке у меня открываеться одина и таже страница(index):

```
if(integer==0) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
            }
else if(integer==1){
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/second.html");
        }
```

integer я достаю с SharedPreferences:

```
package com.example.savedata; 
  
 import android.content.Context; 
 import android.content.SharedPreferences; 
  
 public class PreferenceConfig { 
  
     private static final String MY_PREFERENCE_NAME = "com.example"; 
     public static final String CHOOSELESSON = "choose_lesson"; 
  
  
    public static void registerPref(Context context, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) { 
         SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
         pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener); 
     } 
  
     public static void unregisterPref(Context context, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) { 
         SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
         pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener); 
     } 
  
     public static void chooseLesson(Context context, int total) { 
         SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit(); 
         editor.putInt(CHOOSELESSON, total); 
         editor.apply(); 
     } 
  
     public static int chooseLessonInt(Context context) { 
         SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
         return pref.getInt(CHOOSELESSON, 0); 
     }
```

Запись данных в shared preferences исполняется в другом activity при нажатии на listview:

```
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
                         ListView listView1 = lessonList.get(i); 
  
                         switch (listView1.getId()) { 
                             case 0: 
                                 lesson = 0; 
                                 PreferenceConfig.chooseLesson(getApplicationContext(), lesson); 
                                 CoursePage.this.startActivity(new Intent(CoursePage.this, Lesson.class)); 
                                 overridePendingTransition(0, 0); 
                                 break; 
                             case 1: 
                                 lesson = 1; 
                                 PreferenceConfig.chooseLesson(getApplicationContext(), lesson); 
                                 CoursePage.this.startActivity(new Intent(CoursePage.this, Lesson.class)); 
                                 overridePendingTransition(0, 0); 
                                 break;
```

Comment: Видимо `integer` всегда равен `0`, поэтому вы всегда попадаете на `index.html`. Добавьте деталей в вопрос, приведите код, как вы получаете данные из SharedPreferences, и в какой момент вы пишете туда данные.

Comment: @Vadik,изменил код

Comment: у вас по умолчанию значение 0 если у вас в памяти ничего не записано, очевидно у вас не сохраняется ничего в памяти, попробуйте посмотреть при сохранении то что у вас в памяти по итогу остается. Emulator -> Android/data/data/com.my.package и. там можно посмотреть что у вас хранится в приложении

Comment: @Andrew,папка files и ничего больше

Comment: А где присвоение значения переменной `integer`, вы не забыли это сделать, или может делаете не вовремя?

Comment: @woesss,да, прсвоил не тот Preference, у меня их куча и символом ошибился, спасибо